# dynamic_cast<> against random pointers?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Can `dynamic_cast<>` be used against pointers that may come from some random location.   In other words, a pointer that may point to an `int` or may point to some unknown structure?

If so, how does it access a `vtable` of something unknown; wouldn't attempting to access a `vtable` via the pointer given just be pointing somewhere in memory and could cause a `GPF`?

TIA!!

Comment: Pointers have types. That's what the compiler uses to do the right thing. You can't have a pointer with a "random type".

Comment: Are you hoping to defend against memory corruption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this `dynamic_cast` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

> `dynamic_cast < new_type > ( expression )`
>
> ...
>
> *`expression`*    -   lvalue of a complete class type if *`new_type`* is a reference, prvalue of a pointer to ***complete class type*** if *`new_type`* is a pointer.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

The *complete class type* is important here, as it means you can't really pass any generic pointer to `dynamic_cast`.

The type of *`expression`* must also be *related* to the *`new_type`* (i.e. a base-class, a child-class, or a sibling-class) or the behavior will be undefined.

If you use `dynamic_cast` with any "random pointer" you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and while a compiler might be able to warn you about it (though not always possible) still attempting to do something leading to UB is on you as the programmer.

Comment: Notable exception to this is a dynamic_cast to void*, which has its uses.